# Music: What is the most comparable software bundle to Native Instruments Komplete that is deliverable via internet download after purchase?

Tags: osx, audio, music-production

This is one of the staple sets of software in every studio, containing among other things, the virtual synthesizer Reaktor and over 50GB of samples, at a very affordable price ($500). However, with the recent release of Komplete 10, Native Instruments decided to disallow a downloadable version in the user's online portal area–something that had been the practice since the inception of the product (and is still the case with all of their other products (digital delivery)).

I have a Macbook Pro Retina, and I refuse to spend the extra money to buy a DVD drive just to get a boxed product and have to keep up with the DVDs. Everything is moving to online-storage and online download now, anyway (so if your hard drive crashes, you can just log in and download again, etc).

So, are there any other comparable bundles in this range?

If not with the software instruments, then with the samples, or vice-versa?